# Net Runtime Bug : .NET Runtime 2.0 Error - Event Id: 1000 Crashed my program. What caused this?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clr

I have a new program which has been running 24/7 for over 2 weeks now but last night it crash/went down with no Fatal log exception in my log4net file ...the process appears to have been killed by someting .... and when I looked  in the Windows Event Viewer Application log it contained an error for the programs process saying '.NET Runtime 2.0 Error' Type: Error EventID: 1000.

This appears to be a .Net runtime failure/bug and has nothing to do with my code.

Does anyone know what caused this? Is there a .Net runtime fix?

/I'm running .Net 3.5 on a Window Server 2003 vm slice.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Full event description below. There's were no events around it for hours and there were Info level not Error like this one.

Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error
Type: Error
Event Id: 1000

**Event log description:**
Faulting application CompanyName.AppName.exe, version 0.0.0.0, stamp 4ca5d33d, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3607, stamp 4add5446, debug? 0, fault address 0x0010724e.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: Post all the information from the eventlog entry, as well as related events around it.

Comment: Sorry no memory dump. But what could cause this? A .Net bug?

Comment: Not likely. More likely: crappy hardware. You use ECC RAM? Could just be a flipped bit.

Answer (score 2):

As you are not getting any useful information at the time of the crash, an alternative approach is to attach a debugger to the crashing `EXE`. There are two ways I suggest:

**Using Visual Studio**

If you have Visual Studio installed on the same PC/server as the crashing app, attach Visual Studio to the `EXE` whilst it's running. Here's an intro on how to do this:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/c6wf8e4z%28v=vs.100%29)

**Using WinDbg**

This is a very low-level, and powerful, debugger for Windows. This could certainly help you with your problem. However, there is a steep learning curve in how to get started in using it. The .NET framework comes with a `DLL` named `SOS.DLL` (found in the `C:\Windows\......` system folder) which contains many commands that you can use in WinDbg to analyse a .NET application. These include listing thread stack and displaying exception information.

A very good source of information on how to debug .NET issues with WinDbg is

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/)

There are many great examples of how to debug issues, such as

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/11/net-debugging-demos-lab-2-crash-review.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105094450/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/02/11/net-debugging-demos-lab-2-crash-review.aspx)

You can download WinDbg from:

- 32bit version
  [http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.mspx#E3](https://web.archive.org/web/20110221133326/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.Mspx#E3)
- 64bit version
  [http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/)-

I would highly recommend the Visual Studio approach, due to its simplicity. However, by far the most powerful way to debug your app is to use WinDbg, but it can be intimidating for first time users.

EDIT:
Here's another link that might be of use:

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ebd10d1f-902b-4a95-ba42-e87c4f817097](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ebd10d1f-902b-4a95-ba42-e87c4f817097)

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like a .NET Runtime 2.0 error due to null reference is in the user policy cache. Make sure that you have all the latest .NET service pack installed. Also take a look at [this Microsoft answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/61655c84-c785-4ee7-9607-5847547a5090/receiving-net-runtime-20-error-reporting-eventid-1000?forum=sharepointadminlegacy).

Comment: FYI. The core .NET runtime is still version 2.0, even though the framework is version 3.5. As of .NET framework 4, the core runtime is also at version 4. Was a bit confusing for me in the early days, as I though the runtime was version 3.0/3.5 to sync up with the framework.